# Who is using MS OneNote here?

Tags: scrum, meetings

I would like to know more about OneNote. I am impressed with the capabilities it has.

I make notes of my Daily Scrum meetings, project meetings n stuff. Anyone else who is using this tool and what other things you do with it?

Comment: Hi Raj, we generally look for questions with lots of detail that are about a specific problem you're facing. Can you edit your question so that you're asking about how OneNote could be used to solve a specific problem you're facing? The question has potential, but if you or no one else can edit it to clean it up, it might be closed as not constructive. As it stands, it's simply a polling question, which is off topic. Please be sure to check out the [FAQ](http://pm.stackexchange.com/faq) to get a solid idea of what kinds of questions to ask here. Thanks Raj!

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I know its a very vague question to ask, but I was looking more of an experience stand point of view from users.

Comment: Your question has potential to be a good Q&A question, if edited...  As it stands, this sounds like polling. I encourage you to include as much detail in your question as possible. With lots of detail, the question is more specific and will have more value to not only you but also to our community. Just asking if someone uses a tool or not doesn't provide a lot of value. Check out the FAQ if you haven't done so already. Ways to improve include listing your company culture, whether your agile or waterfall, whether you're a small team or a large team or in an educational institution. Good luck!

Comment: I guess this question is "primarily opinion-based".

Answer (score 2):

I've been using OneNote, since I discovered it was so tightly integrated in Office 2010.

It makes for a seamless workflow for taking notes from Outook meetings, then putting some of those notes into tasks and reminders. Great way to catalog meeting minutes and flagging things for follow-up.

Comment: I agree with that point Kevin. Plus its easy to share with peers all the time. And if you have touch interface with you then it makes more easier to let your fingers to the job ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I also was a user of OneNote but I switched away in favor of [evernote](http://www.evernote.com/). On of my favorite features of onenote is the image-text recognition. Very helpful, when you have attached whiteboard pictures to meeting notes and are able to search upon text within those images.

I have used evernote from everything from helping plan a wedding to planning vacations. Rather than explaining my usage, the evernote blog does a very good job highlighting the applications flexibility: http://blog.evernote.com/category/tips_stories/

Answer (score 1):

I use OneNote for about a year and at this moment I cannot imagine working without it.

I keep there a lot of information cataloged in a way that is most transparent for me.

I have several notebooks for different purposes:

- Project - each of my projects has its section there. In these sections I keep lots of notes, such as

  - Important informations about the project,
  - A list of contact persons,
  - Arrangements with clients. I export e-mails directly from the Outlook, including both findings and attachments, which are always available form me, when I need them.
  - Documentation of the projects

  Each of these sections is divided into the archive and current area. Then it's easy for me to see what is happening at the moment in each project.
  The fact that in OneNote, you can easily group your notes, makes the big image realy clear.
- Meetings - Here goes a lot of information about the meetings. Often, I'm preparing the meeting agenda dividing the subjects to talk on a separate notes, and then during the meeting completing them with what has been established. Then immediately after the meeting I have full information about what has happened there.
  Additionally, for clients with whom I meet often - there are sections named Next Meeting, where I throw everything what I would like to raise at the next meeting. Once it is established, I have all the topics that I would like to talk about.
- Ideas - Notebook was created to store my ideas that I would like to implement, but I still need to think about. During some free time I can go back  and rethink them.
- Important E-mails - Previously, when I did not know OneNote often i was opening important emails I left them for later. It happened sometimes that something has gone wrong and my "list" disappeared after the computer restarted. Now all that important but not urgent mail lands here and in the meantime all the issues can be handeled.

Working with OneNote makes work easier when you rethink exactly what you want to store there. I think that everyone is able to adapt this tool to their needs and over time expand it more and more.

Good integration with other components of Office causes that you can easily flip through the informations to OneNote. In addition, the ability to send e-mails from notes directly from OneNote really makes life easier.

The tool itself really supports work. I also integrate it with the information contained in my personal Kanban board. Since the beginning of working with these tools, my job has become much more efficient and organized.

I really recommend it!

Answer (score 0):

As far as taking notes during any meeting, my preference is always of a tool where I can categorize my notes (for easy referral back), search items and finally easy to share with other team members.

The sharing or collaboration part is important for me - OneNote does well in that you can create a shared notebook that others can also view and edit. In addition, OneNote's formatting and structuring seems more enhanced than Evernote.

If sharing or collaboration of notes is important, Google Docs is another viable tool.